# Wiremock JsonMatcher or JsonPathMatcher not working

Tags: wiremock, wiremock-standalone

I want to match a request body using Wiremock dotnet. Sample request body

{
"name": "ashutosh",
"age": 33
}

I want to match it with one of the key value combination like either age or name.

I tried the below combinations but nothing seems to match

```
"Body":{
        "Matcher": {
            "Name": "JsonPathMatcher",
            "Pattern": "$.[?(@.name == 'ashutosh')]"
            }
        }



"Body":{
        "Matcher": {
            "Name": "JsonMatcher",
            "Pattern": "{ \"age\": 33}"
            }
        }
```

Can somebody help me with this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out the answer. We need to use double dots instead of one dot I have used in JsonPathMatcher like this:

```
"Body":{
        "Matcher": {
            "Name": "JsonPathMatcher",
            "Pattern": "$..[?(@.name == 'ashutosh')]"
            }
        }
```